# Date 24/09/1967 issue GMT +1 and +2 using mdp-date-picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timestamp, timezone, utc

A very strange behaviour occurs using particular date 24/09/1967, this is the date when change in Europe/Italy from +1 to +2 "winter time" .
I have a service that retrieve from backend a timestamp that represent 24/09/1967 date in this format -71715600000.
AngularJs material mdp-date-picker show correctly 24/09/1967.
If I inspect -71715600000 value in https://www.epochconverter.com/ I have this results.
[Epoch converter with -71715600000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50YoL.png)

Than from Frontend without any modification I save my data, and my angular model contains a new timestamp: -71719200000
[Epoch converter with -71719200000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp07r.png)

I notice that from windows machine and chrome browser will be put +2 hours in timezone.
If I do the same things on a linux chrome browser (linux are configured with same timezone of windows +2), timestamp saved from my frontend are always +1.
my question is:

- How is It possible that epoch basing only on -71715600000 timestamp can understand that timezone are +1 and after on the same browser It said that   -71719200000 is +2?
- Why Chrome windows add +2 and chrome linux +1 If I have same timezone configured?
- If I save my date 24/09/1967 from  FE Windows Chrome and save to a BE store procedure fiscal code check there is an error because store procedure need timezone +1. If I save the same date from Linux It works!!

I have no idea... :-( Thanks in advance for all your response.

Comment: The general problem is you are assigning an arbitrary point-in-time to represent a whole date, and then re-interpreting it as a different point-in-time later.   Unix timestamps are always in terms of UTC, but when converted to Italy time, those ones correlate to `1967-09-24T00:00:00.000+01:00` and `1967-09-24T00:00:00.000+02:00`.  Note that both timestamps are valid on this day, as `00:00` is repeated.  `00:00+02:00` came *first* and then an hour later came `00:00+01:00` ([reference here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/italy/rome?year=1967)).

Comment: That said, I can't really answer this question fully without seeing the relevant code, and knowing more about the versions of browsers and operating systems involved.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then come back and edit your question accordingly.  Thanks.